# I want to update kendo grid after update

Tags: angularjs

```
 $scope.AnomalyGrid = {
        dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
            //data: AnomaliesList,
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: logstar.url(getAnomalyItemUrl + '?id=' + id),
                    dataType: "json",
                },
                update: {
                    url: logstar.url(UpdateAnomalyItemUrl),
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json"
```

*This will update the value in server after that i want to refresh kendo grid or call read method of kendo grid. In the responce i am sending updated model .
................... Is there Any success function available after responce in kendo grid.*

```
                },

                parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                    if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                        return { models: kendo.stringify(options.models) };
                    }
                }
            },
            pageSize: 10,
            autoSync: true,
            batch: true,
            schema: {
                model: {
                    id: "CallID",
                    fields: {
                        equiptmentno: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                        currentposition: { validation: { required: true } },
                        isocode: { validation: { required: true } }

                    }
                }
            }
        }),
        columns: [
            { field: "equiptmentno", title: "Equiptment No" },
            { field: "currentposition", title: "currentposition" },
            { field: "isocode", title: "isocode" }              
            { command: ["edit"] }
        ],
        editable: {
            mode: "popup",                
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  update: {    url: logstar.url(UpdateAnomalyItemUrl),
               type: "POST",
               dataType: "json",   
               complete: function (e) {
                 var gridEl = angular.element('#AnomalyGrid');
                 gridEl.data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
                 gridEl.data('kendoGrid').refresh();
                } 
            }
```

*It works responce come at complete segment of code*